# list.get_fields() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jsom, taxonomy

I am trying to get field of a list :

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var web = ctx.get_web()
var list = web.getList(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/lists/DocumentReferences")
ctx.load(list)
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){alert("ok");}, function(){alert("ko");})
```

It's work but, after, if I try to do this :

```
var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("ColumnName");
```

I have this error :

```
list.get_fields is not a function
```

Someone know why?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Please share all of your code since the error is probably there.

I have no problems running this code:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.getList(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/lists/mylist");
var fields = list.get_fields();
ctx.load(fields); 
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){ console.log('success', fields); }, 
   function(){ console.log('error', arguments); } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before to use this line `var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("ColumnName");`

Try to load first your fields as the following

```
var listFields = list.get_fields();
clientContext.load(listFields);
```

And then in the function: onQuerySucceeded

```
var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
    while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var field = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        var name = field.get_staticName();
        if (name == "Colname") {
            docFeatureEnabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

For more details check [Try Get Field with client object model without error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45268/try-get-field-with-client-object-model-without-error)

Answer (score 0):

`executeQueryAsync` has two parameters: the callback function to run when the query is successful, and the callback function to run if the query runs into any errors.

Any code that depends on the query running successfully should be placed *inside* the success callback function (the first parameter of `executeQueryAsync`).

```js
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        alert("ok");
        var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("ColumnName");
        // rest of your code goes here...
    }, 
    function(){alert("ko");}
);
```